# Enlarge font size eps figure

Tags: graphics, subfloats, psfrag

I have two `eps` figures and I'd like to enlarge the font size of labels `Dimension 1` and `Dimension 2` (Figure1) and `Dimension 1`, `Dimension 2` and `Frequency`(Figure 2) in the two figures. This lables should have same size.

## Figure 1

[image]

## Figure 2

[image]

```
\begin{figure}[H]        
        \centering
        \subfloat[Polygonal scatterplot]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.62]{scatter_price.eps}\label{fig:scatter_price}}
        %\hspace*{-2em}    
        \subfloat[Histogram]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.4, trim = 1cm 2cm 1cm 1cm, clip]{hist_price.eps}\label{fig:hist_longair}}
    \caption{Histogram and symbolic scatterplot of response variable} 
\label{descriptive1}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: If I understood what you want, it is not a TeX or LaTeX question. So I think the question has to be closed. I think that you have to use gimp or inkscape on linux (may be on windows too)

Comment: I think you can do it with tikz too but did not thought it before. I have an answer for you in some seconds but as I don't have your images in the specific format you have them, I can not really provide an exact result. I can just give you the idea and the code needed to do it in one only label and you can use it yourself with your specific files.

Comment: Sorry for flagging the question. Didn't thought it could be done at first "sight".

Answer (score 2):

Just the idea:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]      
        \centering
        \subfloat[Polygonal scatterplot]{\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node at (0,0) {\includegraphics[scale = 0.62]{fig1.png}}; % ADDING OUR PICTURE HERE 
        \fill[color=white] (-3.3,-1.5)--(-2.95,-1.5)--(-2.95,1.5)--(-3.3,1.5)--cycle; %HIDING OLD LABEL HERE WITH A RECTANGLE FILLED WHITE
        \node[rotate=90] at (-3.1,0) {\normalsize Dimension 2}; % ADDING NEW LABEL HERE WITH OUR CHOICE OF FONTSIZE (rotate starts from "3 o clock" and goes counterclockwise) 
        \end{tikzpicture}\label{fig:scatter_price}}
        %\hspace*{-2em}    
        \subfloat[Histogram]{\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node at (0,0) {\includegraphics[scale = 0.4, trim = 1cm 2cm 1cm 1cm, clip]{fig2.png}};
        \end{tikzpicture}\label{fig:hist_longair}}
    \caption{Histogram and symbolic scatterplot of response variable} 
\label{descriptive1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Result: [image]

As you see the result is already different from yours because of the different format of the files (mine are png copied of your post)

Suggestion: try with red color in the rectangle until "deleting old label" to see it better.

Comment: I forgot to put the second includegraphics in a "\node at (0,0)" and this is why it is so ungly... but you get the point.

Comment: I use `\Huge` inside figure environment. It's work, thanks.

Comment: Ok. You are welcome... If you need something more just ask for it. You can always print a letter or something (red) to test the place of the points inside a "\node at" command... then after finding the two points it is easy to draw a thin rectangle and last step is to find the rectangle's center and rotate the added text. Good luck